# How can I split a crosstab corner into cells matching the columns below it?

Tags: cognos, cognos-8

When recreating a Cognos 7 report in Cognos 8 I noticed the old report does something my report can't (best I can tell). The report has a crosstab corner split into cells matching the multi-column "rows" part of the crosstab. I tried recreating this in Cognos 8 to no avail.

I can't use the `Structure > Headers and Footers > split list row cell` menu option; that does basically what I want, but only for headers/footers, which I guess this doesn't count as. Closest I came was to use a table inside the crosstab corner":

[image]

This however results in no attempt to match up the corner's cells with the cells below it. And since the content in the "rows" part of the crosstab are of dynamic length, I can't manually play with margins/padding to align this header.

How can I split the crosstab corner into cells matching the columns below it, like you can with Headers/Footers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking with a Cognos 8 consultant **you can't do this in Cognos 8**. The Cognos 7 report could only do it because of how Cognos 7 did crosstabs, which changed. So the best option is to do as I did, make a table with cells and add some padding to try and make the "headers" approximately match the cells below. I recommend using borders on the left/right of the cells to clearly show the separation of the headers.

Comment: Good work on answering your question. Is this still impossible in Cognos 10? I'm llooking for the same solution, though I think I had seen it before somewhere.

Comment: Solution for Cognos 10 Report Studio can be found here: http://naazvilantakath.blogspot.ca/2013/10/cognos-split-crosstab-corner-cell.html